# What are integral curves of $\lambda X$ by knowing integral curves of $X$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Sorry I have a question:

For a vector field $X$, if we know its integral curves then what can we say about the integral curves of $\lambda X$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb R$?

What is the relationship between the integral curves of $X$ and the integral curves of $\lambda X$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb R$??

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is $\lambda$ a constant or a (nowhere-zero) function here? It shouldn't matter, ultimately, but you should convince yourself that the integral curves of the new vector field are—at least locally—reparametrizations of the original integral curves. Note that $\partial/\partial x$ is complete on $\Bbb R$, whereas $x^2\partial/\partial x$ is not complete (and has $0$ as a fixed point). Zeroes of $\lambda$ will definitely cause issues.

Comment: @TedShifrin Many thanks! Sorry I forgot to say that $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is a nonzero constant, then what is the derivative of $\alpha(\lambda t)$? [Presumably we want $\alpha(t)$ to be an integral curve of the vector field $X$.]

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! It is $\lambda \alpha'(\lambda t)$. And I know that we should have $\alpha'(t) = X(\alpha(t)$ and on the other hand we need to find $\beta(t)$ such that $\beta'(t) = \lambda X(\beta(t))$. Now what can we say?

Comment: I say you have it. Just put things together.

Comment: @TedShifrin Many thanks! You mean we should have $\beta(t) = \alpha(\lambda t)$?

Comment: Sure looks like it works!

Comment: @TedShifrin Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @TedShifrin Will the same proof work if $\lambda$ is a nowhere zero function ?

Comment: @ManojKumar: Locally, sure, but as I commented earlier there may be issues with complete vector fields turning into incomplete and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha'(t)=X(\alpha(t))$, and we need to get that $\beta'(t)=\lambda X(\beta(t))$, so in the integral curve $\alpha$ of $X$ we can just replace $t$ by $\lambda t$ to obtain $\lambda\alpha'(\lambda t)=\lambda X(\alpha(\lambda t))$ by the chain rule.

That is: $\beta(t)=\alpha(\lambda t)$, which means that the integral curve of $\lambda X$ has $\lambda$ times the velocity of the integral curve of $X$.